# How to get name of parent from php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data:

```
table(id, parent_id, name)
       1| 0| Apple
       2| 1| Iphone
       3| 1| Ipad
       4| 1| Macbook
```

And mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` AS brand
WHERE brand.parent_id = brand.id
```

But result is null, how to fix this query

Comment: What are you trying to get as output from the query?

Comment: You need to specify `brand.id`.

Comment: FYI: `WHERE brand.parent_id = brand_id` will attempt to retrieve rows where `id` and `parent_id` are the same. It wouldn't make sense for something to be a parent of itself would it!? Instead, you must self join the table onto itself as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Your query is checking if there's a row with the two IDs equal. There isn't in your example. You will probably want the self join suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a self join:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.name AS parent_name
FROM
    tbl a
LEFT JOIN
    tbl b ON a.parent_id = b.id
```

The result set will look something like:

```
id  |  parent_id  |    name       |    parent_name
--------------------------------------------------
1   |  0          |    Apple      |    NULL
2   |  1          |    Iphone     |    Apple
3   |  1          |    Ipad       |    Apple
4   |  1          |    Macbook    |    Apple
```